# Hacking an RC car controller to implement a joystick (PWM)

Tags: analog, pwm, transmitter, motor-controller

My RC car controller (transmitter) has only 4 buttons (left wheel forward /backward, same for right)

I want to implement a joystick using Arduino.

The Arduino will use PWM on the transmitter circuit, and will use four transistors as emulated button. (When I activate the transistor, the transmitter will think the button is activated.)

- Do you think it's possible?
- Do you think it is safe for the transmitter ?
- Is arduino pwm to fast for the transmitter? do I have to make my own slower version of PWM?

Here are some photo of the transmitter:

[image]

[image]

[image]

Comment: This will probably work poorly, as the bandwidth will be low meaning a very low PWM rate.  Instead, consider putting a mini-Arduino with something like an NRF24L01+ module (or whatever 2.4 GHz chip you prefer) in the transmitter, and put another in the car, which (apart from better antennas) is what a number of hobby-grade systems use.  You may be able to tap into the existing H-bridge and drive that for the motor, though for proportional steering you might want to add a cheap hobby servo or even create one by adding a feedback potentiometer to the typical motor-which-stalls steering.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Transistors might work if all the switches connect the inputs to common negative.

[image: schematic]

<sup>[simulate this circuit](/plugins/schematics?image=http%3a%2f%2fi.stack.imgur.com%2fRnMjY.png) – Schematic created using [CircuitLab](https://www.circuitlab.com/)</sup>

If the switches connect one pin of the chip to another then you may have more difficulty. You'll need to trace out the PCB tracks.

[image: schematic]

<sup>[simulate this circuit](/plugins/schematics?image=http%3a%2f%2fi.stack.imgur.com%2fieWTM.png)</sup>

Your micro will have to share the COM (-) with the RC battery negative.

It should work.

Comment: Yes fortunately it's the case :) Sorry about capitalisation